# How to tell which chrome extension is malicious?

Tags: google-chrome

I have a number of chrome extensions. Each seems reliable based on reviews & they function as they claim to. I downloaded them purposefully. But it seems at least one of them has been paid to promote things by randomly opening windows in my browser. I sometimes get redirected to the pages for chrome extensions I have no interest in while doing something completely unrelated. It has also happened that a google search is automatically redirected to yahoo search. This is obviously frustrating and it's time to figure out who the culprit is and uninstall it.

Is there some kind of way of knowing which extension is doing these things? I am looking for a log or console of chrome actions. After google searching, I found an "activity log" but that's only in google chrome canary. It would be a bit of a pain to start using an alpha build of the browser just to debug this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try inspecting the network trace (hit <kbd>F12</kbd> and click the Network tab). Each network trace line has an Initiator column that says what script initiated the network call. If you see any suspicious ones that say `chrome-extension://blarg.../some_file.js-or-html` as the initiator, `blarg...` is the extension ID that initiated the traffic.

If you have a consistent way of reproducing the malicious activity, you could navigate to `chrome://extensions/` and try disabling one extension after another until the malicious activity stops. Then the last one you disabled is the culprit.

You can also just open up the extension source code in `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/*` and inspect the files directly.

I've had an extensions in the past report to Google Analytics without asking (I consider this malicious) so what I did was copy the code out of the extension folder to a separate directory, such as `~/.config/google-chrome-extensions`, delete the appropriate lines that included the `ga.js` file, delete the `_metadata` folder, then added it back to Chrome using the Load Unpacked Extension feature.

Comment: That's very helpful thank you. Seems like the network trace also only saves as long as it is open, but I can't reproduce the malicious activity. Is there an alternative to just leaving it open until the activity reappears?